# Qt 5.14.2 share file on Android

Tags: java, android, qt

I'm trying to share a simple pdf file on Android from my app.
I know from Android 7 the api has changed so i tried to implement my own FileProvider.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="it.semibyte.androidtest.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <!-- ressource file to create -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths">  
    </meta-data>
</provider>
```

This is my file_paths.xml under res/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

And this is my java file

```
package it.semibyte.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
import java.io.File;

import org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative;

public class ShareUtils
{
  public static boolean share(Context context, String filepath)
  {
    if(QtNative.activity() == null)
      return false;

    File file = new File(filepath);
    if(!file.exists())
      return false;

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "it.semibyte.provider", file);

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Share file");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    // Verify that the intent will resolve to an activity
    if(sendIntent.resolveActivity(QtNative.activity().getPackageManager()) == null)
      return false;

    QtNative.activity().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
  }
}
```

I also created a gradle.properties file that looks like this (it is merged with default gradle.properies generated by qt):

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

When i try to compile it gives me this error:

```
ShareUtils.java:7: error: package androidx.core.content does not exist
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider;
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Nothing? I need help

Answer (score 0):

To enable AndroidX in our Qt application, we need to:

1. Add

> GRADLE_OPTS="-Dorg.gradle.project.android.useAndroidX=true -Dorg.gradle.project.android.enableJetifier=true"

to android/gradlew right beneath the 'DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=""' line

2. Add

> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

at 'dependencies' section of android/build.gradle

([more detail](https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/android-development/2020-May/001138.html))

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build.gradle 
`allprojects { repositories { google() } }`

Answer (score 0):

Use this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76320533/qt6-abdroid-open-or-share-a-file-on-android-using-qtapp/76335699#76335699) post in detail.

For your problem, you must add the following block into build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
}
```

and also gradle.properties file must contain the below codes:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```