# Qt6 Abdroid: open and share a file on Android using QtApp

Tags: android, qt, share, qt6

How can I open or share a file on Android using QtApp?
I used the following resources, but I encountered problems with these resources in Q6. They are either lacking, obsolete, or mismatched

1. [ekkesSHAREexample](https://github.com/ekke/ekkesSHAREexample) repository
2. [Sharing Files on Android or iOS from your Qt App](https://www.qt.io/blog/2017/12/01/sharing-files-android-ios-qt-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last few days, I had serious problems with Qt Android and opening and Sharing files, and I did not find the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/ and other related sites. I decided to share the answer here.

I developed a library with all the details and share it using [Github](https://github.com/mohsenkondori/QtAndroidViewShare).
This library uses various resources that had some challenges and limitations. I resolved them and enhanced the library's usability.